# What is the purpose of 'batch_size' here and how can it be defined for other datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been going through [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) tutorial until these lines:

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

I know what a batch file is, but I don't really understand how it is used here and what the value of `batch_size` depends on. If the images in the dataset were 32 x 32, how would it be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch size is the number of samples (images) loaded at a time to train a model with. So you'd load 32 images at a time and feed them to your model.

Comment: So what does batch_size affect? Speed of processing?

Comment: Yes. A large batch size means your model changes in big steps. However, this can also be too big, overshooting the wanted result. Look up batch gradient descent for example. Of course, a large batch also needs to fit in your computer memory.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, it's like step in gradient descent! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think *batch_size* specifies the number of samples used in each iteration. Batch size really depends on your computational power, i.e. smaller batches are preferred for smaller amounts. **img_height** and **img_width** refer to the amount of pixels. Had you 32 by 32 images, they would be 32 and 32.
(Giving a look at the dataset used in the example at the link you provided, it looks like 180x180 is the smallest image size. All pictures have height and width >=180 pixels)